# OrientDB 2.2.2 - Pinned Pages Issue and Implications?

Tags: orientdb

I am seeing an issue with pinned pages after OrientDB starts up and tries to initialize my plocal ODocumentTx DB. I am seeing a repeated message of "Maximum amount of pinned pages is reached" upon startup, and it doesn't finish initializing. After changing storage.diskCache.pinnedPages from 20 to 50, the message is displayed several times, then startup continues as normal.

What are the implications of making this change, and why is it occurring on startup? Is there a way to avoid this from happening even at 50%?

Answer (score 1):

Pinned pages is special area of disk cache which unloaded from RAM only when OrientDB storage is closed. It is used in OrientDB clusters and hash index to speed up performance of storage operations.

You are probably getting this message because the client doesn't have enough memory.

Comment: We are running on 32 bit, so the only way to resolve/avoid this is to ensure that are client has enough memory?

Comment: Yes, pinned pages use RAM.

Comment: Why would this issue occur on startup? Assuming we have the max amount of ram per process available for our client (~1.4gb on 32bit). What action does OrientDB do, while initializing a present DB.